# KeystoneJs Edit form shows "Meta" label

Tags: mongoose, keystonejs

Keystone Js Edit form shows "Meta" label at end of each form in Admin UI.
Attached is screenshot to give you clearer view.[image: encircled part is issue]

How to get rid of this label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a label that tracks the `createdAt`, `createdBy`, `updatedAt`, and `updatedBy` fields. If you are tracking any of those fields (determined by the `track` option when creating the list), the Meta field will always appear.

If you know you will not be using it *ever*, you can use a custom stylesheet and select the last `h3.form-heading` element and hide it. Create a `less` stylesheet and point Keystone to it via the `adminui custom styles` setting on `keystone.init`.

```
keystone.init({
    // ...
    "adminui custom styles": "public/styles/admin/admin.less",
    // ...
});
```

You might have other headings within your page that separate sections of your document; this only selects the last one.

```
.EditForm-container h3.form-heading:last-of-type {
    display: none;
}
```